# How to eliminate grey areas and Antartica from a Map?

Tags: r, ggmap

I don't know how to eliminate two areas from a map: the Antartica and a grey region appearing on the top, right and left of the image.

I tried with almost all the answers here, but in some cases the results appearing after executing the code are not even similar of the answers, my guess is in some cases the answers are a little older and the original function has changed after 5 or 6 years.

```
gc <- geocode('spain')
center <- as.numeric(gc) 
map <- get_map(location = center, source="stamen", zoom=1)
ggmap(map)
```

This is the original code that create a world map. I want to set the limits to avoid all the grey part and also the antartica.

If I change the zoom = 2, I lost Australia.

Actual results:

[image: grey and Antartica included into the map]

Expected results:

[image: Map without grey areas and Antartica]

Answer (score 0):

```
 cities <- c('usuahia','alaska','new_zealand','greenland_sea')
 lat <- c(-54.80191, 64.20084, -27.46977,77.870977)
 lon <- c(-68.3030, -149.49367, 153.025124,-5.650146)
 limits <- data.frame(cities,lat,lon)

 mbound <- c(min(limits$lon), #min/max longitude/latitude to display on the map
         min(limits$lat),
         max(limits$lon),
         max(limits$lat))

 worldmap <- get_stamenmap(bbox=mbound, zoom = 3)

 [![enter image description here][1]][1]ggmap(worldmap)
```